# Connect Laptop to Conference center audio system through Microphone input

Tags: audio, interface

I want to play a video on a conference centers audio system. I saw the conference center interface the 2 with a microphone preamplifier. The input to the conference centers audio is a standard round 3 pin microphone connector in the floor. I am looking to build a 3 pin microphone connector to a box with a rheostat for volume control and to the laptop through the small 3 wire 3.5mm plug on the laptop. It sounds easy and that is why I am checking here.  Any drawings or schematics out there?
Thanks,

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Rode-VXLR-Adapter-VideoMic-Mini-Jack/dp/B000Y021NA

Comment: Are you sure the conference center doesn't have a standard 3.5mm input? They might not like you using a generic adapter on their probably thousand+ dollar ssyrem.

Answer (score 2):

> a standard round 3 pin microphone connector

XLR connector.

> small 3 wire 3.5mm plug on the laptop

Almost certainly a headphone output

The headphone output from a computer has very different characteristics to the output from a typical microphone.

I suspect you'll need some active device to adapt the audio levels and impedances. There are [DI boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DI_box) for this sort of job.

[Example](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/530095-REG/ART_AVDIBOX_AV_Direct_Multi_Input.html)

> The ... is a direct box with a very specific purpose. It is the ideal solution for any situation where stereo iPods, **notebook computers**, consumer DVD players HiFi equipment or video machines have to be connected to a **single XLR microphone level input**.